# Query to find if a column contains both number and decimal only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column to check if contains number from 0-9 and a decimal. Since in the version of SQL am using the below does not seem working

```sql
select *
from tablename
whwere columnname like '%[^.0-9]%'
```

Also tried using column name like '%[0-9]%' and columnname not like '%.%' but if there is a negative sign it is not getting captured. Please advise.

The column data type is float. So can someone provide me a query to check if the column contains values from 0-9 and also it can contain decimal values these two are permitted. If say for example if I have value 9,9.99 ,-1.24 the query should output -1.24 I need this value other than decimal and number –

Comment: If you want a column to only contain a decimal value, why not define is as `decimal`/`numeric` rather than a `varchar`? Then it can only store numerical values in the first place. Defining your data types correctly is *incredibly* important.

Comment: Also, the reason  your query isn't working is because you mispelt `WHERE` (`whwere`).

Comment: The data type of `columnname` matters.  The `LIKE` operator works on character columns, not numeric columns. Please [edit] your question to show us some sample data and the definition of the column.

Comment: the coulmn data type is float .so can u provide me  a query to check if the column contains values from 0-9 and also it can contain decimal values these two are permitted .if say for example if i have value 9,9.99 ,-1.24 the query should output -1.24 i need this value other than decimal and number

Comment: @sara . . . Your question is entirely unclear.  A floating point value is stored using an internal format.  When represented as a string, it can only have digits, `'.'`, and `'-'`.

Comment: @sara, I'm also confused by your question but perhaps you want `columnname < 0 or columnname >= 10` to identify values outside that range.

Comment: @sara if 0-9 are valid, your given example should provide the output `9` only - `9.99` is above the maximum, `-1.24` below the minimum...

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your LIKE clause is bad predicate logic `...like '%[^.0-9]%'`should be `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'`

Take this sample data.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (SomeNbr VARCHAR(32));
INSERT @table VALUES ('x'),('0'),('0.12'),('999'),('-29.33'),('88.33.22'),('9-9-'),('11-');
```

What you were trying to do would be accomplished like this:

```
SELECT t.someNbr
FROM   @table AS t
WHERE  someNbr NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%';
```

The problem here is we'll also return "88.33.22" and miss "-29.33", both valid float values. You can handle hyphens by adding a hyphen to your LIKE pattern:

```
SELECT t.someNbr, LEN(t.SomeNbr)-LEN(REPLACE(t.SomeNbr,'.',''))
FROM   @table AS t
WHERE  someNbr NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%';
```

But now  we also pick up "9-9-" and stuff with 2+ dots. To ensure that each starts with a number OR a hyphen, to ensure hyphens only exist in the front of the string (if at all) and that we a maximum of one dot:

```
--==== This will do a good job but can still be broken
SELECT t.someNbr
FROM   @table AS t
WHERE  someNbr NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%' -- Can only contain numbers, dots and hyphens
AND    LEN(t.SomeNbr)-LEN(REPLACE(t.SomeNbr,'.','')) < 2 -- can have up to 1 dot
AND    LEN(t.SomeNbr)-LEN(REPLACE(t.SomeNbr,'-','')) < 2 -- can have up to 1 hyphen
AND    PATINDEX('%-%',t.SomeNbr) < 2 -- hyphen can only be in the front
```

This does the trick and returns:

```
someNbr
--------------------------------
0
0.12
999
-29.33
```

All that said - **DONT DO THIS ANY OF THIS ^^^ **. There is no need to parse numbers in this way except to show others why not to. I can still break this. They way I return valid floats in a scenario like this is with [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This returns what you need and will perform better.

```
--==== Best Solution
SELECT t.someNbr
FROM   @table AS t
WHERE  TRY_CAST(t.SomeNbr AS float) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: 1 thing the test example you give is with a varchar column, the op was asking about a float column. 2nd, Your final "best solution" could really be up at the top of the answer, almost didn't see that part, and yet it is quite a good idea!